# iOS - GANTracker nothing to dispatch

Tags: objective-c, ios, google-analytics

I'm attempting to install the Google Analytics SDK in my iOS app to track page views and events. Having followed the documentation provided, I cannot seem to get tracking working at all and am wondering can anyone help me out? The following info may be relevant - I'll try to be as descriptive as I can.

- I am targeting all devices from iOS 4.3 and up.
- I have included GANTracker.h in my project-prefix.pch file and it builds ok

Below is a sample from my appdelegate.m code which is called in the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method

```
/*  Google Analytics tracking code  */

[[GANTracker sharedTracker] setSampleRate:100];

[[GANTracker sharedTracker]setDebug:NO];

[[GANTracker sharedTracker] setDryRun:NO];

[[GANTracker sharedTracker] startTrackerWithAccountID:@"UA-111111-1"
                                       dispatchPeriod:kGANDispatchPeriodSec
                                             delegate:self];
NSLog(@"Dispatch%@", [[GANTracker sharedTracker] dispatch] ? @"ed Successfully": @" Failed");

NSError *error;
if (![[GANTracker sharedTracker] setCustomVariableAtIndex:1
                                                     name:@"iPhone"
                                                    value:@"iv1"
                                                withError:&error])
{
    NSLog(@"There was an error setting this custom variable\n Description: %@\n", [error localizedDescription]);
    NSLog(@"Failure reason: %@\n", [error localizedFailureReason]);
    NSLog(@"May we suggest: %@\n", [error localizedRecoverySuggestion]);
}

if (![[GANTracker sharedTracker] trackEvent:@"Loading"
                                     action:@"App Finished Launching"
                                      label:@"appDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions"
                                      value:-1
                                  withError:&error])
{
    NSLog(@"There was an error in tracking events\n Description: %@\n", [error localizedDescription]);
    NSLog(@"Failure reason: %@\n", [error localizedFailureReason]);
    NSLog(@"May we suggest: %@\n", [error localizedRecoverySuggestion]);
}

NSString *pageUrlString = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://ios.organisation.tld/appentrypoint"] stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
if(![[GANTracker sharedTracker] trackPageview:pageUrlString withError:&error])
{
    NSLog(@"There was an error in tracking initial app entry\n Description: %@\n", [error localizedDescription]);
    NSLog(@"Failure reason: %@\n", [error localizedFailureReason]);
    NSLog(@"May we suggest: %@\n", [error localizedRecoverySuggestion]);

}
```

In my app view controllers I want to track pageViews and am soing so the following way:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
[super viewWillAppear:animated];
NSError *trackError;
NSString *pageUrlString = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/aboutsection"] stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
if(![[GANTracker sharedTracker] trackPageview:pageUrlString withError:&trackError])
{
    //Handle error here
    NSLog(@"There was an error tracking this pageview\n Description: %@\n", [trackError localizedDescription]);
    NSLog(@"Failure reason: %@\n", [trackError localizedFailureReason]);
    NSLog(@"May we suggest: %@\n", [trackError localizedRecoverySuggestion]);
}
}
```

Going back to my appdelegate.m I also have the following delegate set up

```
- (void)trackerDispatchDidComplete:(GANTracker *)tracker eventsDispatched:(NSUInteger)hitsDispatched eventsFailedDispatch:(NSUInteger)hitsFailedDispatch
{
    NSLog(@"Google analytics dispatch\n Succeeded?:\n %i, \n Failed?: %i", hitsDispatched, hitsFailedDispatch);
}
```

This logs as something like Succeeded?: 5 Failed?: 0 so no failures coming up there

I also see a log message ...nothing to dispatch. Logging into Google Analytics I see no visits coming up. Looking at realtime analytics also shows nothing happening.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: As it turns out, the code above is fine. I made the simple mistake of using the wrong version of the SDK. The Google Analytics service provides two types of dashboards. One for websites and one for apps. Version 1.4 of the SDK is designed to push page views and events to a UA code which is supposed to be set up as a website. In my case it was set up as an app so although the requests were being made, they were being dispatched to nowhere. I was able to solve the problem in two ways. 1 ) Create a new dashboard as a website and use the UA code for that or 2 ) Use my existing UA id SDK version 2.

Answer (score 0):

It only worked when i tried this steps :

1- at appdelegate .h class #import "GAI.h"

2- at appdelegate in function "didFinishLaunchingWithOptions" add this codes

```
 // Optional: automatically send uncaught exceptions to Google Analytics.
    [GAI sharedInstance].trackUncaughtExceptions = YES;
    // Optional: set Google Analytics dispatch interval to e.g. 20 seconds.
    [GAI sharedInstance].dispatchInterval = 20;
    // Optional: set debug to YES for extra debugging information.
    [GAI sharedInstance].debug = NO;
    // Create tracker instance.
    [[GAI sharedInstance] trackerWithTrackingId:"your tracking application id from google analytics"];
```

3- at any uiviewcontroller class . h #import "GAI.h"

4- at .h replace this part ":uiviewcontroller" with ":GAITrackedViewController"

5- at .m add in view did load this line

```
[[[GAI sharedInstance] defaultTracker] trackView:"your view title"];
```

- Be careful about point number 5 , must be implemented by this way i think the GA library has issues in any other way and in documentation too . i tried and searched alot about this issue and by accident it worked by this way only, beside it's the fastest way to show the effect at GA screen.
- anther note : you must create your app for mobile at google analytics , take care about the ID of application to add it Correct at IOS application